# Setting up SSL virtual hosts in Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl

I'm trying to set up SSL, with SNI, in my apache and am getting the often-seen "ssl_error_rx_record_too_long" error in Firefox when accessing the site (https://test.me.dev.xxxx.net), from which I can conclude that the server is listening on port 443, but doesn't know to use SSL on it.

The server is Ubuntu 9.04 with Apache 2.2.11
I enabled SSL in the default way (a2enmod ssl).

Here is my relevant config:

```
NameVirtualHost *:*
Listen 80

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>
```

...

```
<VirtualHost *:*>

        DocumentRoot /home
        ServerAlias *.dev.xxxx.net
        UseCanonicalName Off
        # project.user.dev.xxxx.net
        VirtualDocumentRoot /home/%2/dev/%1/web

        SSLEngine On
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/certs/dev.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/certs/dev.key

</VirtualHost>
```

What is wrong?

Comment: `mod_ssl` didn't have SNI (Server Name Indication) support until Apache 2.2.12, yours is just a little too old.

Comment: Also may be helpful: http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/NameBasedSSLVHostsWithSNI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is part of my server working config. Hope you will it handy.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@xxx.com
    ServerName  xxx.com
    ServerAlias www.xxx.com

    DocumentRoot /srv/www/htdocs/xxx.com

    ErrorLog  /var/log/apache2/xxx.com-error_log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/xxx.com-access_log vhost_common

    <Directory "/srv/www/htdocs/xxx.com">
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mail.xxx.com
    Redirect / https://mail.xxx.com/
</VirtualHost>

<IfDefine SSL>
<IfDefine !NOSSL>
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@xxx.com
    ServerName  mail.xxx.com

    DocumentRoot  /srv/www/htdocs/roundcube

    ErrorLog  /var/log/apache2/roundcube-error_log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/roundcube-access_log vhost_common
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/roundcube-ssl_log ssl_combined

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP:+eNULL
    SSLCertificateFile    /etc/ssl/xxx/apache2.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/xxx/apache2.key
    SetEnvIf User-Agent ".*MSIE.*" \
        nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
        downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
</VirtualHost>
</IfDefine>
</IfDefine>
```

Comment: So there's no way around duplicating the config for sites that need access via both?

Comment: If you want to force either SSL or non-SSL you can configure Apache to redirect to the other (i.e. if you force SSL, then have the non-SSL do automatic redirect to the SSL domain).  This shortens your config because it's just a one line redirect.  Otherwise you should use Include statements as a way to follow DRY principles and shorten the config.

Comment: @Bart van Heukelom: To configure similar virtual hosts, put the common directives in a separate file and use the Include directive.  Alternatively, use mod_macro http://www.cri.ensmp.fr/~coelho/mod_macro/ .

Answer (score 0):

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: But I also need sites to be available over normal HTTP